# dividing the table for the result

Tags: html

I have a query that selects the names in the table.
and I wanted to divide the result into 15 names per table data.
is it possible that the next 15 names will display in the next table data? how?

```
 <?php
    extract($_POST);
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Individual"){
    if(isset($submitsearch)){
        //if(!empty($searchquery)){
        $sql    = "SELECT * FROM contact_individual WHERE name LIKE '%$searchquery%' ORDER BY name";
        $query  = mysql_query($sql);
        $count  = mysql_num_rows($query);

            for($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
                $data   = mysql_fetch_array($query);
?>
<table class="tsearch">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form method="GET" action="resultindividualprofile.php">
                <input type="text" name="text" hidden="hide" value="<?echo $data['contactID_individual'];?>"/>
                <input type="submit" class="rep" name="this" value="<?echo $data['name'];?>"/>
                <!--<a href="?view=<?php //echo $data['contactID_individual']; ?>"><?php //echo $data['name']; ?></a>-->
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: It's highly unrecommended to use `extract` with user input like `$_POST`. By default, `extract` would overwrite existing variables, making it very easy for a user to inject a value to your script.

Comment: (Related to the edit you suggested on the answer) If you want to add a printscreen, add it to your question not to an answer.

Comment: I added your printscreen.

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<?php 
if($_POST['filter1'] == "Individual"){
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM contact_individual WHERE name LIKE '%".$searchquery."%' ORDER BY name";
    $query  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count  = mysql_num_rows($query);
?>
<table class="tsearch">
<?php 
$x=0;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{     
    if($x > 0 && $x%15==0)
    {
       echo '</table><table class="tsearch">';
    }       
?>

<tr>
    <td>
        <form method="GET" action="resultindividualprofile.php">
            <input type="text" name="text" hidden="hide" value="<?echo $data['contactID_individual'];?>"/>
            <input type="submit" class="rep" name="this" value="<?echo $data['name'];?>"/>
            <!--<a href="?view=<?php //echo $data['contactID_individual']; ?>"><?php     //echo $data['name']; ?></a>-->
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php $x++; } ?>
</table>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why it doesn't work? What's the result you are getting? Are you getting more than 15 results

Comment: i updated my answer. Just check with this. You will get error if you will have.

Comment: What's there in this variable : $searchquery ?

Comment: a text form. because i have there a search bar

Comment: Just `echo` your `$sql` and see what's the `query`.

Comment: i already tried this one. but the result showed the first members name

Comment: yah its working. but what i wanted is that, the result should be 15 per table data

Comment: the result is the same with the code i have posted a while ago

Comment: Are the results more than 15?

Comment: i have in my database 70 records. and the result displayed 70 records.

Comment: i highlighted all the result and it is by 15 records. but the result is still a long line. what i wanted is the every 15 records will be displayed in the first table data and the succeeding 15 will be on the other table data.

Comment: Can you attach the screenshot of the result and the code as well?

Comment: can you see the printscreen?

Comment: i cant post the picture because i dont have 10 reputations as of now

Comment: but the result is a straight line of names from the database.

Comment: i saw it, you just post the screenshot of source code in comment.

Comment: Just `echo $x` along with the name and see what's there in `$x`

Comment: $x is the count of the name.

Comment: If you will `echo $x`, it will display like 0,1,2,3,.... Is it happening? After `echoing $x`, can you post screenshot of the page?

Comment: Just post a screenshot of the source code of the page. Like when you do view source in browser, that source code.